# Bootstrap Page Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a quick question on a site that I'm building. It seems that something is pushing the width beyond the window causing a horizontal scroll, and the footer isn't filling the the full width (with a 100% width set).

Can anyone provide any insight?

URL is http://www.brandography.org/sticknfind

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: it's the slider which is causing problem..I'm looking into the code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with

```
<div id="content" class="row">..</div>
```

In bootstrap "row" class has negative left/right margin. As per bootstrap documentation, rows should be placed inside container for proper padding. When you initialize slider, it will calculate wrong content width because of that. Try this instead

```
<div id="content" class="container">..</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The width of your slider div is more than that of the body.
You can fix this by either:

_ Adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to your `body` tag.

_ Putting a wrapper div around your content and add `overflow-x: hidden;` to that div.